# Can two GWT modules in the same project access the same database on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, module, google-cloud-datastore, gae-module

I'm planning to divide my GWT project into two different [modules](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideModules).

In my project I'm using the [Google Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/).

The question is if the two modules will be able to access the same Datastore or not (I would like them to).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your GWT projects are served from your one appengine app then yes.  They will both call servlet RPCs on your appengine app and that will access the same database.